# (UK English?)How do I have to understand the meaning of 'house' in 'Prior(priory) of London house'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, synonyms

What would be the synonym for 'house' in 'Prior(y) of London house'? 
(I haven't known there are such various ways to interpret the word 'house'...)

- edit : *"However, in November of that year, he was elected Prior of the London house, to which he returned."*

Comment: This phrase means nothing to me in either version. Where have you seen it?

Comment: [Priory Hospital, Roehampton, often referred to as **The Priory**, is a private mental health hospital in South West London.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priory_Hospital) But I wouldn't call it a "house".

Comment: There's some kind of online feature to train their translation program and I only brought a small part of one sentence to here.. It seems I should have written the whole sentence. I will edit the OP~!

Comment: Vastly insufficient context.

Comment: Although I agree that the question has grossly insufficient detail, it does pertain to something that many English learners will find obscure (namely the field of meaning of "house") and has an excellent answer. So I vote not to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*It would have been helpful* if the OP had mentioned that the sentence comes, as Google reveals, from the Wikipedia page about John Houghton (c. 1486 – 4 May 1535), a Carthusian hermit and Catholic priest. The 'house' here is the London Charterhouse, which was, prior to the reign of Henry VIII, a Roman Catholic monastery belonging to the Carthusian Order.

[John Houghton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Houghton_(martyr))
[Carthusians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthusians)
[Charterhouse (Monastery)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charterhouse_(monastery))

Regarding the usage of 'house', this word can be used for many types of building, not just a family domestic residence.

> house
>   noun (PUBLIC BUILDING)
>   a building or part of a building that is used for a special purpose

or -

> A house can also be a building or part of a building which is used by
>   an organization:

[House (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/house)

Comment: Thank you for finding the original context..! So it was a monastery :) Your explanation is helpful. (The site I mentioned in the reply section usually provides only a small portion of some random paragraphs, hence the insufficient context.)

Comment: You can do a Google exact text search by enclosing the text in double quotes like this: "However, in November of that year, he was elected Prior of the London house, to which he returned." [link here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=%22However%2C+in+November+of+that+year%2C+he+was+elected+Prior+of+the+London+house%2C+to+which+he+returned.%22&oq=%22However%2C+in+November+of+that+year%2C+he+was+elected+Prior+of+the+London+house%2C+to+which+he+returned.%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1100.1100..1608...0.0..0.63.63.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.tqGjbpqpG-g&ved=0ahUKEwixxa73hd7mAhUIKBoKHfLxDbkQ4dUDCAg&uact=5)